# Write to global ViewBag from partial view in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In an application written with ASP.Net Core 2.0, how can I in a partial view write to the global ViewBag? The partial get's its own local ViewBag so anything I write there won't be stored in the global ViewBag it seems.

For example, let's say that the "Home/Index" view renders a partial "_TitleBar", inside this partial we set ViewBag.PageName = "MyPage". Now, later in the same request, in "_Layout" I want to render whatever value is stored in ViewBag.PageName. This does not work in the above scenario. So how can I access the global ViewBag from my "_TitleBar" so that this value can be picked up elsewhere ?

For now, the workaround is to store data in TempData instead which is global.

Answer (score -1):

Razor renders the actual page then the layout then the partial views, and that's why partial views cannot have features such as sections. You can do this using `JavaScript` or `JQuery` without relying on Razor. All you have to do is to add a script in the partial view to update the `PageName`. For example:

```
_Layout.cshtml
------------------
<title>Site Name | Page Name </title>

_partial.cshtml
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         document.title = "new title";
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but then it seems like an easier solution to keep using TempData instead.

Comment: @NeoDarque: I don't think relying on `TempData` would be an easier solution and in the meanwhile, it is not a good approach. Assuming that all of that server side coding would eventually be rendered to plain HMTM/Javascript by the Razor view engine, you'd better rely on client side coding in the first place.